# Haskell design: Struggling with IO

Tags: haskell

I am a novice haskell programmer and I am trying to write some Haskell cgi which will read from a MySQL DB and output JSON. I am able to generate the right JSON but am unable to get the data types correctly to be able to output JSON correctly. I also think that I am primarily thinking imperative still. Here is my code. Note that getTopBrands provides json output.

My problem is that I am unable to figure out how to return "[Char]" from getTopBrands and not "IO [Char]". It looks to me I am still thinking imperative. Any pointers, suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to provide the rest of the code.

RODB.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards, OverloadedStrings, PackageImports #-}

module Main where

import RODB
import ROOutput
import System.Environment
import Database.HDBC
import Network.Socket(withSocketsDo)
import Network.CGI
import Text.XHtml
import qualified "bytestring" Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LBS
import Data.Aeson

page :: Html
page = body << h1 << str

main = runCGI $ handleErrors cgiMain

cgiMain :: CGI CGIResult
cgiMain =
    do out <- getTopBrands 10 1
       setHeader "Content-type" "application/json"
       output $ renderHtml page out

getTopBrands :: Integer -> Integer -> IO [Char]
getTopBrands limit sorted =
    do let temp = 0
       dbh <- connect "127.0.0.1" "ReachOutPublicData" "root" "admin" "/tmp/mysql.sock"
       if sorted == 1
       then do brandlist <- getBrands dbh limit True
               json <- convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON brandlist
               return $ LBS.unpack json
       else do brandlist <- getBrands dbh limit False
               json <- convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON brandlist
               return $ LBS.unpack json
```

Comment: What's the problem with `IO` here? After all, the result of the function *is* dependent on the outcome of an I/O-operation, so I wouldn't consider this bad style. The more apparent problem here is the `sorted` parameter, which has type `Integer`. If it had type `Bool`, you could pass it along directly to `getBrands` without the ugly branch and code duplication. I also don't see why `convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON` would need to live in `IO`, but since you didn't provide its definition I cannot suggest an improvement here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Niklas B said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932128/haskell-design-struggling-with-io#comment22697093_15932128), `getTopBrands` being in `IO` is right, since it depends on I/O. I guess your problem is that you get a type error from that when you try to use it directly,

```
cgiMain :: CGI CGIResult
cgiMain =
    do out <- getTopBrands 10 1
       setHeader "Content-type" "application/json"
       output $ renderHtml page out
```

since all statements in a do-block must belong to the same monad, and the rest of the block is in `CGI`. But, `CGI` is a [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cgi/latest/doc/html/Network-CGI.html#t:MonadIO), thus you can simply `liftIO` it into `CGI`,

```
cgiMain :: CGI CGIResult
cgiMain =
    do out <- liftIO $ getTopBrands 10 1
       setHeader "Content-type" "application/json"
       output $ renderHtml page out
```

The next point Niklas raised is also right, the second `Integer` argument of `getTopBrands` should really be a `Bool`. However, even with its current type, the code duplication is entirely unnecessary, the difference between the two branches is just the `Bool` argument to `getBrands`, so

```
getTopBrands :: Integer -> Integer -> IO [Char]
getTopBrands limit sorted =
    do let temp = 0
       dbh <- connect "127.0.0.1" "ReachOutPublicData" "root" "admin" "/tmp/mysql.sock"
       brandlist <- getBrands dbh limit (sorted == 1)
       json <- convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON brandlist
       return $ LBS.unpack json
```

*just pass it the condition on which you branched*.

Niklas' third point

> I also don't see why `convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON` would need to live in `IO`, but since you didn't provide its definition I cannot suggest an improvement here.

also looks very valid, a conversion would usually be a pure function. If the only reason why it is in `IO` is the ability to write

```
json <- convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON brandlist
```

you should be aware that you can bind results of pure functions in a do-block

```
let json = convPublicBrandEntrytoJSON brandlist
```

using `let`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, liftIO did the job for me.